# How to tunnel device with ssh server in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have ssh access and connect that with the `dartssh2` package. Like this:

```
final client = SSHClient(
  await SSHSocket.connect('address', port),
  username: 'username',
  onPasswordRequest: () => 'password',
);
```

Now, I want to create a VPN profile to tunnel devices with get permission access from the user and tunnel traffic with an ssh server. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

*(Despite ChatGPT saying there's no way to do it, your question helped me)*

I was able to do it this way, I have to connect to my server and forward all traffic through the port `27700`.

```
      final String keyPem = """
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
<YOUR_KEY>
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
"""; // You can also grab it from a File, check the `dartssh2` documentation
      final String keyPemPassphrase = "<YOUR_PASSPHRASE_FOR_THAT_KEY_PEM>";

      final SSHSocket socket = await SSHSocket.connect("<DOMAIN_TO_CONNECT>", $PORT_TO_CONNECT);
      final SSHClient client = SSHClient(
        socket,
        username: "<USERNAME_FOR_SSH>",
        identities: [
          ...SSHKeyPair.fromPem(keyPem, keyPemPassphrase),
        ]
      );

      final ServerSocket serverSocket = await ServerSocket.bind(
        'localhost', // Where you want to forward it
        27700, // Port where you want to forward it
      );

      await for (final Socket socket in serverSocket) {
        final SSHForwardChannel forward = await client.forwardLocal(
          '192.168.202.17', // Internal port at the domain of the computer
          27700, // It's port
        );
        forward.stream.cast<List<int>>().pipe(socket);
        socket.pipe(forward.sink);
      }
```

works like a charm